# How can I print a question with many pages in pagination?

Tags: discussion, support

I want to print some community wiki questions, but they span many pages, like 6 or 7. When I print it only gets the content of the first page.

How can I print I pages in one go?

I would like to make a PDF file of it, and then I would like to print it.

Comment: Use http://www.stackprinter.com/, together with a PDF print driver.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [StackPrinter](http://www.stackprinter.com/) as indicated by [Michael Petrotta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155847/how-can-i-print-a-question-with-many-pages-in-pagination#comment448010_155847).

I have created a SEDE query as an answer on: [Dump of my own Stack Exchange content](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269804/dump-of-my-own-stack-exchange-content/269951#269951). You can fork that query if you don't want all content of a user but only subsets or even a single post. The printing can then be done with your favorite browser to an PDF printer.

An other alternative might be [Print this post](https://stackapps.com/questions/3307/print-this-post) but that would require you to click print for each question/answer.